# Xcode 5 adding a project dependancy issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode5

After upgrading to `XCode 5`, I can no longer add project dependancies to an `XCode` project. Projects created with `XCode 4` preserve the dependancies but don't accept new dependancies. Projects created with `XCode 5` don't accept new dependancies at all. And because an image is worth a thousand words...

This is what happens when I have done drag and drop a Child Project to the Parent Project:

[image]

As you can see the Child Project is added but it doesn't link to the parent. If I click on it, it displays a blank content, like it can find no more.

Any ideas why is this happening?

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Xcode has (AFAIK) always done this when the child project is also open  in its own window. Close both projects, then re-open the parent. The child project should (hopefully) show up as expected!

Comment: Great! Glad it helped… I'll put it as an answer so you can close it off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode has (AFAIK) always done this when the child project is also open in its own window.

Close both projects, then re-open the parent. The child project should (hopefully) show up as expected!